# Filter a rest service by category or field

Tags: json, rest, xpages

I am using the extension library's rest control to provide a json data feed. Is it possible to filter by a category or a field with a URL parameter?

I understand that I can use a search string "&search=something" but that can provide me with erroneous results. I have tried searching for a field equal to some value but that doesn't seem to work for me.

If I cannot do this with the rest control, is it possible with Domino Data Services?

Comment: There are quite some flavors of rest services. View document custom - which one did you try? Can you provide the code you tested?

Comment: I will get some code up. I am using the extension library with a view json service though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter by a category or field value in a viewJsonService if you add `?keys=yourValue` to URL.

The REST service returns the same documents as you would get with view.getAllDocumentsByKey("yourValue").

Default is non-exact-match filtering which means that only the beginning of column value has to match. If you want the exact match then add `&keysexactmatch=true` to URL which would be the equivalent to view.getAllDocumentsByKey("yourValue", true).

*Example:*

Assuming, we have a view "Forms" with a first sorted column "Form".

With the REST service

```
<xe:restService
    id="restService1"
    pathInfo="DocsByForm">
    <xe:this.service>
        <xe:viewJsonService
            viewName="Forms"
            defaultColumns="true">
        </xe:viewJsonService>
    </xe:this.service>
</xe:restService>
```

and the URL

```
http://server/database.nsf/RestServices.xsp/DocsByForm?keys=Memo&keysexactmatch=true
```

we'd get all documents with Form="Memo" as JSON

```
[
  {
      "@entryid":"7-D5029CB83351A9A6C1257D820031E927",
      "@unid":"D5029CB83351A9A6C1257D820031E927",
      "@noteid":"11DA",
      "@position":"7",
      "@siblings":14,
      "@form":"Memo",
      "Form":"Memo",
      ... other columns ...
  },
  ... other documents
]
```

We'd get the same result if the first column is categorized.

Comment: hello Mr knut HerrMann , I am doing the same thing as you explained in the answer and also it works very fine but i upgraded to FP8 the categorised views returns java null pointer error, i posted the same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47752975/rest-service-returns-nothing-on-keys-and-column-value-is-null-pointer