# Rest Service returns nothing on keys and column for Categorised View when Upgraded from FP6 to FP8

Tags: rest, xpages

I am working in the application in which I have implemented the search and passing the "searchKeys" in url by Rest Service xpage,

In fix pack 6 I get the results as expected but the same application i configured in a server with Feature Pack 8, the keys in the Rest service simple returns nothing and in Categorised view I update the Keys with Categorised column value which returns Null pointer .

if I tries to get the categorised columns results I get the error

```
{
    "code":500,
    "text":"Interner Fehler",
    "message":"",
    "type":"text",
    "data":"java.lang.NullPointerException\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewNavigatorFactory$ViewNavigatorNavigator.getTopLevelEntryCount(RestViewNavigatorFactory.java:644)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewNavigatorFactory$SearchKeyNavigatorNavigator.getTopLevelEntryCount(RestViewNavigatorFactory.java:581)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewItemFileService.renderServiceJSONGet(RestViewItemFileService.java:263)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.rest.das.view.RestViewItemFileService.renderService(RestViewItemFileService.java:77)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.services.HttpServiceEngine.processRequest(HttpServiceEngine.java:168)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService._processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:257)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.extlib.component.rest.UIBaseRestService.processAjaxRequest(UIBaseRestService.java:234)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.util.AjaxUtilEx.renderAjaxPartialLifecycle(AjaxUtilEx.java:206)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.renderAjaxPartial(FacesServletEx.java:249)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialView(FacesServletEx.java:200)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceAjaxPartialViewSync(FacesServletEx.java:169)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.serviceView(FacesServletEx.java:155)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:159)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.FacesServletEx.service(FacesServletEx.java:138)\r\n\tat com.ibm.xsp.webapp.DesignerFacesServlet.service(DesignerFacesServlet.java:103)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:588)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.invokeServlet(NSFComponentModule.java:1335)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$AdapterInvoker.invokeServlet(ComponentModule.java:865)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule$ServletInvoker.doService(ComponentModule.java:808)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.ComponentModule.doService(ComponentModule.java:577)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFComponentModule.doService(NSFComponentModule.java:1319)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doServiceInternal(NSFService.java:662)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NSFService.doService(NSFService.java:482)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.doService(LCDEnvironment.java:357)\r\n\tat com.ibm.designer.runtime.domino.adapter.LCDEnvironment.service(LCDEnvironment.java:313)\r\n\tat com.ibm.domino.xsp.bridge.http.engine.XspCmdManager.service(XspCmdManager.java:272)\r\n"
}
```

In the case of search the Keys in Rest Service the error is simply Empty

```
  {
"@timestamp":"2017-12-11T12:24:41Z",
"@toplevelentries":1799,
"items":
[
]
}
```

Note : Same thing works with FP6 but Dont Works with FP8

Comment: That could be db corruption.  Try deleting the view and replacing the design with a template taken from a known good copy.  You may also want to have a look at the view in the notes client and make sure it is built properly (Shift + F9 to rebuild).

Comment: Still dont found any thing on this also tested on new database, but on FP 6 works fine with same code.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue in my project. You get nullPointerException because the REST service returns nothing (Null). Hence, while loading the data (null data) in the REST service to grid the code that loads the data should handle the exception. Below code may help you on this.

```
listeners: {
    exception : function(proxy, response, operation) {
    operation.records = []; //set the value of exceptional data to blank.
}
```